# Websockets in Yesod?

Tags: haskell, websocket, yesod

I would like to create a website using Yesod and websockets (html5).

Can I use websockets with Yesod webframework?

Comment: Have you seen: https://github.com/yesodweb/wai/blob/master/wai-websockets/Network/Wai/Handler/WebSockets.hs

Answer (score 5):

Yes, as Thomas M. DuBuisson pointed out in the comments: a WebSocket handler is implemented in WAI which is the interface Yesod is using to communicate with it's backends. I can't comment on how well it works in it's current form, but you can download and try it from [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-websockets).